# What is the fastest search algorithm for a list with names and numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, sorting

The list has names and numbers. Each name has a number. The list is sorted by name and the numbers in the list's are sorted least to greatest. I need to find the ***sum of all the largest numbers*** associated with ***each name***.

```
a 1, a 4, a 5, b 0, b 4, c 1, n 9, n 10
```

I would need to out put

```
5 + 4 + 1 + 10 = 20
```

I need to do this in **O(logn)** time.

Comment: Looks like homework which should be done by your own

Comment: You can't sort `n` elements in `O(log n)` time as checking all elements would have a complexity of `O(n)` already. If you're after `O(n * log n)` complexity then there are quite a lot of fitting algorithms. Just look them up and use one you like.

Comment: At first - what is n?

Comment: You can't do this in logarithmic time. In the worst case, every name has just one number, so you'd have to add them all: you can't add n arbitrary numbers in sublinear time.

Comment: O(logn) is only possible if you have an additional constraint on the number of different names in your list. If the number of different names is (close to) logn, you can construct an algorithm that would be O(logn) in the average case (using the knowledge of how the list is sorted)

Comment: If you know the names in the list already, then simply take an upperbound on each of the names. This is the best you can do and it runs in O(M*log(N)) where M is the number of names and N is the total number of elements in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code, find last O(log N) of each name O(M).

```
auto it = vec.begin();
while (it != vec.end()) { // O(M)
  auto last = find_last_with_same_name(it, it->name); 
  sum += last.value;
  it++;
}
```

Use [exponential_search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) for O(log N) for finding the last and therefore largest value.

For a total of O(M log N).

If M, the number of names is a constant you get O(log N), but that would need some rules lawyering.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Scan the list, maintaining a "largest number in the current run" and an "accumulator for the sum". Every time an element differs from the previous, accumulate the current largest number and reset it to the value of the element.

I let you take care of proper initialization and finalization.

This is Θ(n) and you can't make it faster. 
In the worst case, if all names are different, you need to output the sum of all numbers and this cannot be done without reading them all (as said by Andy).